# iframe src based on javascript variable value

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have  a Iframe, and how to pass a javascript vairable to along with a iframe src.

```
ex:
var param1=test1;
```

how to pass "param1" value along with the iframe url.
and i want to pass like this.

```
<iframe frameborder=0 src="http://cart.demo.com/c_jp.php?action=param1" name="navigationframe" id="navigationframe" width="220" height="800">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to pass the JS param value to the url (as you have it in your code) you can try one of the following:

```
window.frames[navigationframe].location = window.frames[navigationframe].location +      "&param1" = + param1;
```

or

```
document.getElementById(navigationframe).src = document.getElementById(navigationframe).src + "&param1" = + param1;
```

If this is the only variable you will be "passing" to the QueryString then make sure you format the QueryString properly (if it is the second or N+1 variable prepend '&' if it is the first prepend '?')